# Why the variable resets to 0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to make a web aplication for a mobile computer -> [Datalogic Skorio](http://www.datalogic.com/eng/products/automatic-data-capture/mobile-computers/skorpio-x3-pd-337.html).
It'll add up the quantity until the user inputs 0.
The thing it's that everything that its going to add up the counter variable gets reset to 0.

Here's the code

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Quant()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Quant(Qnt qnt)
{
    int qunt = 0;
    string user = (string)TempData.Peek("user");
    string pass = (string)TempData.Peek("pass");
    motorp.AbreEmpresaTrabalho(Interop.StdBE900.EnumTipoPlataforma.tpProfissional, "DEMO", user, pass); // this part it's for using an external software that contains the products and everything.
    while (qnt.qntd != 0 )
    {
        qunt = qunt+qnt.qntd; 
        return View();     
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Fin");
}
```

View:

```
@using Trabalho1.Models
@model Qnt
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Quantidade";
}
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title </title>
</head>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <label>
                <p>Quantidade desejada:</p>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.qntd, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </label>
             <p>@Html.Raw(ViewData["qunt"])</p> \\ ignore this line.testing something
            <button class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
        }
    </div>
    <div class=" row">
        <div class="col-md-2">0)Sair</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Can you try to reword it?

Comment: Can you debug "qnt.qntd"? Is it casted into a correct number?
Moreover: your "int qunt" in the controller is local (so it resets to 0 every time you execute that method)

Comment: can you show the model..also specify the exact error throwing out..alos like JanMoller the qunt value will always reset to 0 each time of posting

Comment: And there is really no point in using `while (qnt.qntd != 0 )` since there can only ever be one iteration at most because exit immediately using `return View();` - just use `if (qnt.qntd != 0)`

Comment: I mean it isnt really an error,the variable qunt gets reset to 0. But from what I can read in the comments the problem it's that the variable it's local ence will make it reset to 0 everytime the user inputs a number. But still thank you for your opinions.

Comment: @Ruben all are not saying error is not because of that..you should specify where the error is coming and what is the exact error code..

Comment: @Sachu let me rephrase, I didn't wanted to mean Error it's more like Iwanted to mean that  I needed to know why the variable was resetting to 0.

Comment: @Ruben when user enter the value each time from view it will come to this controller .so it will execute the statement int quant = 0..thats why it is getting reseted..Also like Stephen said since only one iteration will happen while loop also dont have any role there because inside the loop u are calling return View().Hope you got it.

Comment: @Sachu yes i kinda get it now, thank you :)

Comment: @Ruben see the explanation..will make more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user enter the value in View it will come to the post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Quant(Qnt qnt)
{
.....
}
```

inside this method you are declaring a variable `int qunt = 0;`
 Also in while loop you are checking `qnt.qntd !=0` if not then it will enter the loop and make the sum, but next line is `return view();` so it will return to the view again. Then the user type the value then the process cycle starts as mentioned above.

```
EG: **`Cycle 1`**
    User entered 2
    Control come to the controller
    qunt is set to zero //qunt = 0
    checking 2 != 0 // true
    Enter the while loop
    qunt = qunt + 2 // qunt = 0 + 2 = 2
    return view()//go to the view again

   **Cycle 2**

    user entered 5
    Control come to the controller
    qunt is set to zero //qunt = 0 --rested 2 to 0 here
    checking 5 != 0 // true
    Enter the while loop
    qunt = qunt + 5 // qunt = 0 + 5 = 5
    return view()//go to the view again

    **Cycle 3**

    user entered 0
    Control come to the controller
    qunt is set to zero //qunt = 0 --rested 5 to 0 here
    checking 0 != 0 // false
    wont enter the loop
```

Hope you understand. So atlast the value inside the qunt will be 0 and there is no need of while loop because on first looping itself it will return to the view.